# Trouble connecting to my Home SSH connection

Tags: networking, ssh

> OS: Ubuntu Budgie Remix 16.04
>
> uname -a: Linux midgard 4.8.0-54-generic #57~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 16:22:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This seems pretty basic, but I've tried a whole bunch of things and this is not working. Here are the details.

Situation: I'm running sshd on port 3791 on my residential connection (to avoid the simple network scan, trying to find obvious ssh daemons)

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 3791
```

Problem: No connectivity

```
albion@midgard:~$ ssh {myIPv4OrIPv6} -p 3791 -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to {myIPv4OrIPv6} port 3791.
debug1: connect to address {myIPv4OrIPv6} port 3791: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host {myIPv4OrIPv6} port 3791: Connection timed out
```

Things I've verified:

1. I've nmap'ed localhost and are able to see the open port
2. I've ssh'd into localhost and am able to log in successfully
3. Checked iptables ('sudo iptables -L') for any rules and there is nothing.
4. Also disabled ufw doing 'sudo systemctl stop ufw' just in case.
5. My router is configured to allow Port Forwarding on port 3791 to my LAN address (192.168.0.2) on the same port.
6. I've disabled the options the router-level Firewall.
7. Called my ISP just to check if they had any ideas and, of course, they didn't.

Can anybody think of anything worth checking?
One curious thing is that I'm able to ping and get a response when I'm pinging my IPv4, but I don't get any answers when I ping my IPv6. This might be unrelated but thought I'd mention.

Comment: Is `{myIPv4OrIPv6}` your host's LAN-side IP address, or your router's WAN-side address? Are you trying to connect from inside your LAN (which requires that your router supports [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)) or from outside?

Comment: Please excuse me if this is redundant, you say you have ssh'd into the localhost, is this from the server machine using username@localhost or is this from another machine using the LAN IP?

Comment: Also for S&G, if you temporarily configure it to connect via Port 22, do you have the same issue? It could be the issue with permissions/root privileges? It sounds like all your ducks are in a row otherwise. This isn't a "You need to use Port 22", this is trying to narrow the issue down so we can help you resolve it.

Comment: @Robby1212 From the server machine using user@localhost.
I also tried doing everything on traditional port 22, assuming that maybe the ISP was blocking unrecognized traffic, to no avail :(

Comment: @steeldriver I'm trying to connect using the WAN-side address, though I admit I'm a bit confused on this because I believe that the IPv4 is the same for all devices in the network, but the IPv6 isn't, so for IPv4 I'd need port forwarding but it seems like I shouldn't for IPv6. Either way, port forward is already setup.

Comment: @steeldriver You might be up to something here. I tried connecting via my cell phone to my computer, using IPv4 and I couldn't, but then I tried IPv6 and I could :/

Comment: Can you try using user@LANIP from another machine in the LAN, sometimes the localhost can act differently than using the LANIP from another machine. For example if I try to ssh into my server using user@localhost I get permission denied because I have key encryption turned on.

Comment: It almost sounds like one of the IPs might not be pointing in the right location. Can you add the output of sudo grep sshd /var/log/auth.log to your question? This will tell us if your attempts are actually reaching the server. Please redact any sensitive information of course.

Comment: @Robby1212 I can get through if I ssh into my LAN IP (192.168.0.2) from my same computer or through another one I have hooked on the network.

I don't think it's that useful to show you what's on /var/log/auth.log. I just verified and it basically shows all the right things when I do connect, but when I try to connect using my external IPv4 or IPv6 IP (on the same computer), I get no logs whatsoever.

Comment: By the way, this seems to be 'solved' in the sense that I can access from other computers (which is really the point). Having said that, I'm still puzzled as to why I can't access from my own computer using the external IPs.

Comment: @Albion see my original comment about NAT loopback

Answer (score 2):

Highlighting @steeldriver's answer as I think it was the right one.

Apparently the issue is my routers lack of support for NAT Loopback:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback

This seems to be the case due to the fact that I CAN connect to my computer from other computers in the network if they use the internal LAN IP (e.g. 192.168.0.2) *as well as* externally, if they use my IPv6 IP.

So the solution is:

1) When connecting from the same network, use the LAN IP (or localhost, if its the same device)
2) When connecting from outside, use the IPv6 address (if your ISP gives you one) or the IPv4 one (provided you set up the port forwarding rules).

Thanks @steeldriver!